# Can I take a 240 volt 33 amp male plug an slice

Tags: electrical, subpanel

Okay. So I wanna wire my garage. My old home has an old unused 3 prong 240v plug just chilling. My home is limited to 100amps. Old old home. So, the garage, 60ft away has no power. No power=no man zone. I would like to run a couple different options. Sub-panel or just an extension with a gfi outlet. 
I'm thinking about splitting the plug via a Junction box (new) prior to the old 3 prong plug *and remove said plug. 
My understanding of it is that it's running 2 hot and a neutral. Can I split the hots (2) to create more plugs and lights. Really just want 3 exterior led lights for motion detection and lights outside. Inside I would like modernized  with a plug that can go 120/240 with 20 amps (so I can run my arc welder that requires a min of 20 amps on high or 15 amps on low- it needs a dedicated circuit so as not to be interfered when welding if I have a radio on and light. Help! Man in distress lacking a cave! 
Or what are some better options?

Comment: Please hire an electrician before you burn your house down.

Comment: @user54042 Please contact the support team to [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use existing wiring to feed a sub-panel.  (you cannot put a plug on a sub-panel as far as I know.)  If the wiring is not quite long enough to reach your sub-panel location, put a junction box there and splice to an additional cable.

Your sub-panel **absolutely requires a ground wire** to the main panel.   Grounds can only be bare wire, green or green/yellow.  If the inspector sees any insulation other than that color, it cannot be a ground wire.

If your wire also has neutral, then you can make your sub-panel a 120/240V sub-panel.  Here's the trick: In the sub-panel, **neutral must be isolated from ground**.  Most panels give you a way to do that, by removing bonding straps or removing green screws.

If your wire does not have neutral, your **sub-panel will be 240V only**.  Use 2-pole breakers and NEMA 6 receptacles.  If you power anything hard-wired, make sure it is 240V friendly - most new fluorescent ballasts are multi-voltage, as are many other products.

If you need to run 120V-only appliances out of a 240V-only panel, they sell step-down transformers for sane prices.

Answer (score 0):

Jay welcome to stack exchange. You can create a sub panel from your house to the garage it will take a minimum of 3 wires and possibly 4 depending on where you live. 2 hot 1 ground, 1 neutral. The ground and neutral need to be isolated in a sub panel. The big question is the size wires. Wire size depends on the breaker you will be feeding it with and the type of load. a continuous load requires 125%  where non continuous loads only require 100%. The size of the load 30A to provide an example. With a 30A load you need to make sure your voltage drop is less than 3% I use this [handy voltage drop calculator](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm). i put in 240v 30 amps 3% copper and it returned #10 (#10 is the minimum size for a 30 amp breaker) here in the U.S. standard breakers close to the size you need are 25,30,35. if you go to 35A you will need larger wire. I hope this helps.